# Why does the Euler characteristic of a toric variety equal the number of vertices in the defining polytope?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

In [this link](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/Trevisan.pdf), Corollary 3.2.2, page 59 the author claims that: The Euler characteristic of the toric variety $X_K$ associated to a convex polytope $K$ is the number of vertices of $K$.

I want to see how it works.  Could someone please illustrate this for me by using this method to compute the Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{1}$?  Thanks so much.

Comment: I added the 'toric-variety' label.

Comment: I've changed the title and some wording.  I hope this is acceptable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Merely observe that a toric variety is the union of torus orbits $(\mathbb C^\*)^r$ for various dimensions $r$, and that the Euler characteristic of $(\mathbb C^\*)^r$ is zero if $r>0$ and $1$ if $r=0$.

Vertices of a polytope correspond to 0-dimensional orbits, $r$-dimensional faces -- to $r$-dimensional orbits.

$\mathbb P^2$ corresponds to a triangle, $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ to a square. It is not very hard to count their vertices.

Comment: More generally, if a circle $S^1$ acts on a manifold or the 1-dimensional torus $C^*$ acts on a complex algebraic variety then the Euler characteristic of the "whole" = the Euler characteristic of the fixed point set. This is a very powerful tool in topology.  